# How to check whether DISPLAY can be opened with PyQt4?

Tags: linux, pyqt4, x11

I would like to test whether graphical interface is available when running a program which optionally uses PyQt4. If I do

```
$ DISPLAY= python
>>> import PyQt4.QtGui
>>> PyQt4.QtGui.QApplication()
: cannot connect to X server
```

python crashes (`$?`=`1`).

It is not enough to check for `DISPLAY` environment variable (the value could be invalid, XAuth could fail etc.)

What is the proper way to detect dysfunctional display with PyQt4?

---

My current approach is a bit of hack (I would like to avoid using [python-xlib](http://python-xlib.sf.net), since it does not seem to be maintained):

```
import XLib.display:
   XLib.display._BaseDisplay()
   # display was opened fine, PyQt4 won't crash
except:
   # don't use PyQt4 since display had some error
```

Comment: You're setting X11's `DISPLAY` variable to `python`?

Comment: `DISPLAY=` with the **space** after it sets `DISPLAY` to nothing and runs python (you can try that).

Answer (score 0):

Since Qt insists on crashing the process, you could do a test in another process:

```
import subprocess, time, sys
p = subprocess.Popen(sys.executable, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write('from PyQt4 import QtGui\napp = QtGui.QApplication([])\n')
p.stdin.close()
time.sleep(0.1)
if p.poll() != 0:
    try:
        p.terminate()
    except OSError:
        pass
    print "No X server"
else:
    print "X ok"
```

The timeout might be too short if it's a networked X connection..